# Killing a Thread in Crystal lang

Tags: multithreading, crystal-lang

I wrote a program a crystal program to calculate prime numbers upto a range with Sieve.

### Code

```
#!/usr/bin/env crystal

def sieve(max)
    t = Thread.new do
        dot, ary, colours = ".", ["\xE2\xA0\x81", "\xE2\xA0\x88", "\xE2\xA0\xA0", "\xE2\xA0\x84"] * 2, [154, 184, 208, 203, 198, 164, 129, 92]
        print "\e[?25l"

        loop do
            ary.size.times do |x|
                print("\e[2K#{ary[x]} \e[38;5;#{colours[x]}mPlease Wait#{dot * x}\e[0m\r")
                sleep(0.1)
            end
        end
    end

    s = [nil, nil] + (2..max).to_a
    s.each do |x|
        next unless x
        break if (sq = x ** 2) > max
        (sq..max).step(x) { |y| s[y] = nil }
    end

    puts "\e[?25h"
    s.tap { |x| x.compact! }
end

p sieve(2_000_000).size
```

### The way I want to display it is

[image]

### Issue

The problem is the thread isn't killed when puts is writing the sieve. the method sieve(n) just returns an array. The array size then is calculated, and printed. You can see that the animation freezes for a time, and then continues until it's printed and exited. If I use `spawn do...end` the print in spawn pauses until the sieve is calculated.

Not killing threads causes issues like this
[image]

In ruby I used to do

```
t = Thread.new { loop while ... }
<some other time consuming stuff here>

t.kill
return calculated_stuffs
```

### Crystal Details

Crystal 0.31.1 (2019-10-21)

LLVM: 9.0.0
Default target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu

---

How to kill a thread in crystal?

Comment: You could add a boolean "keep_running" or a channel you could send a message to, to that thread, like "stop running" and poll it every so often, FWIW...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Thread` is part of Crystal's internal API, and is not meant to be used directly.

The good news is Crystal natively supports a concurrency model called [CSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communicating_sequential_processes), where Fibers (light-weight threads) send each others messages over thread-safe Channels in order to coordinate. So, rather than communicating by sharing state, Fibers share state by communicating - as they say in `golang`.

For your use case, you could run 3 Fibers:

- A sieve, generating numbers and sending updates through a channel
- A monitor, receiving on the sieve's channel, updating the UI and sending a completion message once the sieve is done
- The main Fiber, waiting for the monitor to notify completion and able to decide what to do with the sieve's result

[image]

Here is what your code could look like

```
record Result, primes : Array(Int32)
record Tick
alias SieveUpdate = Result | Tick

def monitor(updates : Channel(SieveUpdate)) : Channel(Result)
  Channel(Result).new.tap { |done|
    spawn do
      dot, ary, colours = ".", ["\xE2\xA0\x81", "\xE2\xA0\x88", "\xE2\xA0\xA0", "\xE2\xA0\x84"] * 2, [154, 184, 208, 203, 198, 164, 129, 92]
      ary_idx = 0
      update_n = 0
      print "\e[?25l"
      loop do
        case value = updates.receive
        when Tick
          next unless (update_n+=1) % 50 == 0 # lower refresh rate
          print("\e[2K#{ary[ary_idx]} \e[38;5;#{colours[ary_idx]}mPlease Wait#{dot * ary_idx}\e[0m\r")
          ary_idx = (ary_idx + 1) % ary.size
        when Result
          puts "\e[?25h"
          done.send value
          break
        end
      end
    end
  }
end

def sieve(max) : Channel(SieveUpdate)
  Channel(SieveUpdate).new.tap { |updates|
    spawn do
      s = [nil, nil] + (2..max).to_a
      s.each do |x|
          updates.send(Tick.new)
          next unless x
          break if (sq = x ** 2) > max
          (sq..max).step(x) { |y| s[y] = nil }
      end

      updates.send Result.new(s.compact.as(Array(Int32)))
    end
  }
end

updates = sieve(2_000_000)
done = monitor(updates)

print done.receive.primes.size
```